# Canvas Context manipulation with React

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a sketchpad, where hovering the mouse over should leave a trace on the canvas.

For some reason, every point on my canvas is weirdly connected to that diagonal. Did I screw up something on the canvas manipulation?
[image]

This is my code

```js
const {useRef} = React;

function DrawingPad() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [width,height] = [800,500];
  const prevpos = React.useRef({x:0,y:0});

  const currentpoint = e =>{
    const rect = canvasRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x:e.clientX - rect.left, y:e.clientY - rect.top}
  }
  const mousemove = e => {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
    const {x,y} = currentpoint(e);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevpos.current.x,prevpos.current.x);
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
    ctx.stroke(); 
    prevpos.current = {x,y};
  }


  return (
    <canvas 
      ref={canvasRef} 
      width = {width} 
      height = {height}
      onMouseMove={mousemove}/>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<DrawingPad />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I didn't use any states because I don't need any rerenders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.moveTo(prevpos.current.x,prevpos.current.x)`

in above line second argument to moveTo function should change to prevprops.current y. typo?

Comment: Thank you, it has been a very long day...it works now

Comment: welcome.  you can sense that slope is 45 degrees which means points on line have equal x,y coordinates. :)